# Program UI Slider

Tags: python

I would like to add a slider to my own panel. How can i do that and how can i then read the value from it and assign it to a variable?
I already tried this:

```
row.prop(bpy.props.FloatProperty(name="maxdist", description="test", default=3.0, min=0.0, max=10.0, soft_min=0.0, soft_max=10.0, step=1, precision=1, unit='NONE', update=None, get=None, set=None))
```

And i get this error:
TypeError: UILayout.prop(): error with argument 1, "data" -  Function.data expected a AnyType type, not tuple

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks, Nebeig

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To edit a value in a panel, the value needs to be a property of an item, such as the scene or object. You use [`bpy.props`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html) to add new properties to existing classes. For example :-

```
bpy.types.Object.myprop = bpy.props.FloatProperty()
```

You can then display that property in a panel. You add the `slider=True` option to have it display as a slider.

```
row.prop(context.object, 'myprop', slider=True)
```

Comment: When i try to read value from the slider with bpy.context.object.myprop and then use that value in another pyhton file (via import from) it says : RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded.

Comment: You don't import the `bpy.context.object.myprop` from another script. Both scripts have `import bpy` and directly read `bpy.context.object.myprop`.

Comment: oh, yes that did the trick for me. Thank you