# Add UI slider to custom panel via script

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

I am pretty new to scripting in Blender and I am trying to make a test UI panel with sliders. I made a custom property like this:
[image: Custom Property]

This is what I am trying to do:
[image: My attempt]

I have already tried doing this:

Link1: [Add custom property to panel](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/148924/add-custom-property-to-panel)

Link2: [Program UI Slider](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/115019/program-ui-slider)

What happens is that a slight amount of space is left where I the slider should come, but it does not show up.

This might be really easy for many of you, but it is new and tough for me. Please answer as though answering to a complete newbie.

Comment: Hello ! You need to replace `=` with `:` in the property definition

Comment: @Gorgious, as I have mentioned above, I am beginner. So, please bear with me and tell me what, in this script is the "property definition"?

Comment: Alright, so a bit of advice which would have saved both me and you a bit of time : when you want to troubleshoot code, please post the code as text, not as an image. that way it's easier for others to copy/ paste it and debug it. :) Replace `slider = bpy.props.FloatProperty(name = "Slide number:")`with `slider: bpy.props.FloatProperty(name = "Slide number:")` do the same for `textbox` and `dropdown` (btw you have a duplicate entry for `textbox`, I'm not sure but it might not behave correctly, please keep only one of the two statements)

Comment: I will check and get back to you

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you so much for telling me this, @Gorgious. Now I can finally move forward to creating my addon.                                                                                     Just asking, can you tell me which property to use if we're creating a button?

Comment: you need to use an operator https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Operator.html for the class and https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.UILayout.html#bpy.types.UILayout.operator for the layout element. There are several example builtin Blender if you go to the text editor > templates > python > operator

Comment: Thnx, @Gorgious